# Ubuntu apps on Windows with WSL uninstalled

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL with the Ubuntu distro on my Windows 11 laptop.  I wanted to show some Ubuntu GUI applications, so I installed `tasksel`.  Then, from `tasksel`, I installed Ubuntu Desktop and few more things.

Now, I've uninstalled Ubuntu from the "*Apps & Features"*.  But after uninstalling, I still have Ubuntu apps in the Windows Start menu.

I've also disabled *"Windows Subsystem for Linux"* in *"Turn Windows Features on or Off*", but `wsl.exe` is still here, too.

How do I remove these items?

*I'm new to Linux and Stack Exchange. I'm sorry, but my English isn't perfect. I'm Czech.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts that you are asking about:

###### `wsl.exe` remaining after uninstall/disable

First, the `wsl.exe` command itself comes with a base Windows 11 installation and can't be uninstalled.  Even with Windows Subsystem for Linux completely disabled, it will still exist as an "installer" so that you can `wsl --install` to reconfigure it.  By itself, `wsl --install` will:

- Enable the WSL feature
- Enable the Virtual Machine Platform feature (a subset of Hyper-V for WSL2)
- Install the latest official Linux kernel available for WSL2.
- Install an Ubuntu distribution.

Once WSL itself is *enabled*, then `wsl.exe` is used to control your Ubuntu (or other) distribution.

###### Ubuntu GUI app icons remaining in the Windows Start menu after uninstalling Ubuntu

As for the Start menu items created for Ubuntu GUI apps ...

I'm going to over-summarize slightly here to skip some of the [technical details](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#wsl-dynamic-virtual-channel-plugin-wsldvcplugin) - Those particular Start menu icons are created by WSLg monitoring  for changes in the `/usr/share/applications`.

When a new `.desktop` file is created there of the right type, Windows creates a link to `wslg.exe` in the Start Menu that can launch that particular app.

When a corresponding `.desktop` file is removed (typically via `sudo apt remove <package>`), the Start menu link is removed.

However, if you completely remove the Ubuntu distribution from WSL itself, then WSL can no longer monitor it for changes.  While it would be nice if WSL "cleaned up" these Start menu items when a distribution is uninstall entirely, that's just not the case right now.

---

*Updated:  As of the latest Preview release of WSL (available to Windows 11 users in the Microsoft Store), this is [reported to be fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.61.4):*

> *Remove WSLg icons when a distro is uninstalled.*

---

You can easily delete these manually, but make sure you remove the right thing:

- Find any one of the items that you want to remove in the Start menu.
- Right-click it, choose *"Open File Location"* (or your local equivalent, of course).
- You should find *all* of the Start Menu items for WSL in that folder, under the *"Programs"* folder.  Make note of the folder name.
- Left-click the *"Programs"* folder in the File Explorer address bar to move up one-directory (or via <kbd>Backspace</kbd>)
- Right click on the folder where those items were (likely named "Ubuntu"), then choose *"Show more options"*, then *"Delete"*.

All of the Start menu items that were created by WSLg/Ubuntu should be gone.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D